# Making a virtual file in Linux

Tags: linux, file-io, filesystems, virtual

I'm working with some existing software that I cannot change, and it loads its config data from a bunch of config files, all following the same naming scheme - let's say, file_param1.conf, file_param2.conf, file_param3.conf etc. The difference between the content of the files is just param1 vs param2 vs param3, so a typical config file will look like

```
foo=bar
x=param1
```

or

```
foo=bar
x=param2
```

Is there any examples anywhere on creating a virtual fs in Linux that would let me on access of file_param1.conf generate the file dynamically with the appropriate param variable? I know about scriptfs but not about any tutorials on using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting as an answer because this is too long for a comment.)

You might find it easier to use an `LD_PRELOAD` library and interpose on the `open()`/`fopen()`/`open64()` or whatever exact library call(s) your existing software uses to access your configuration file and replacing the application-supplied file name with one that points to the file you want to use.

This code is off the top of my head and I haven't tried compiling it:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

// don't want to #include anything else or we're likely to get
// the vararg prototype for open()
int strcmp( const char *s1, const char *s2 );

// typedef a function pointer
typedef int ( *open_func_ptr_t )( const char *, int, mode_t );
static open_func_ptr_t real_open = NULL;

int open( const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode )
{
    // find the real open() call
    if ( real_open == NULL )
    {
        real_open = ( open_func_ptr_t ) dlsym( RTLD_NEXT, "open" );
    }

    if ( 0 == strcmp( pathname, "/path/to/config/file" );
    {
        pathname = "/path/to/replacement/config/file";
    }

    return( real_open( pathname, flags, mode ) );
}
```

That code relies on the fact that although `open()` is declared as a varargs function because of the restrictions placed on current C code, originally C didn't have prototypes so all functions were *de facto* vararg functions.  The `open()` call only accesses the `mode` argument when needed, so `open()` doesn't always need to be passed a `mode` argument.  With current C, the only way to do that is with a vararg function.  That makes #include files problematic with this code as any declaration of `open()` will be the vararg one and that will cause the code to not compile.  You might need to replace `mode_t` with `int` (or whatever it's `typedef`'d to) in order to compile.

Compile that with `cc [-m64|-m32] -shared source.c -ldl -o mylib.so`.  You need the `-ldl` to link in `dlsym()`, and you need the proper `-m64` or `-m32` option to get a 64- or 32-bit library to match your application.

Then set `LD_PRELOAD` to your .so file:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mylib.so
export LD_PRELOAD
```

Then run your application with the `LD_PRELOAD` set.  You also need to be real careful that any child processes spawned by your application are all the same 32- or 64-bit as the shared object `LD_PRELOAD` is set to.  If you nave mixed 32- and 64-bit processes to deal with, read the [man page for ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and pay particular attention the the *$PLATFORM* section.

Note also that the code is not reentrant because of the race condition modifying `real_open` and might have problems with multithreaded access to `open()`.